# How can I tell aptana to automatically add the eggs included in the buildout?

Tags: aptana

I'm using Aptana3 to write a python app. Also, I write a buildout.cfg and virtualenv to make the process repeatable and isolated. Thus, packages are installed using:

```
virtualenv env
env/bin/python bootstrap.py
bin/buildout
```

as commonly we do in python projects.

To save space I configure Buildout to store the automatically downloaded eggs into the ~/.buildout/eggs folder. But not all eggs in that folder are used by my project, there are eggs from other projects to.

In Aptana I created a pydev project that uses the env/bin/python interpreter. The problem is that this environment doesn't include the eggs that are installed using buildout and Aptana makes alerts. So I used Omelette to create symbolic links to used packages in the folder parts/omelette and I add that folder to the interpreter package, but it continues showing error messages.

How can I configure Aptana to avoid that error messages?

Answer (score 0):

If buildout is creating `.egg-link`s, you might be being bitten by this bug: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4945

I think Aptana will find need them if you add `~/.buildout/eggs` to your `PYTHONPATH`.